# Post-commit hook failed (exit code 3) with output

Tags: eclipse, svn, jenkins

I'm trying to call a Jenkins job remotely using a post-commit script. I'm currently committing code through Eclipse Kepler/Subversive/SVNKit Connector.

post-commit script:

```
if svnlook dirs-changed -r "$REV" "$REPOS" | grep -qEe '^trunk/'; then
  wget --post-data="job=APS-RemoteServerAction&token=SECRET&ACTION=deploy&ASSET_NAME=POST-COMMIT-TEST&DEPLOY_ENV=DEV&REVISION=$REV" "http://my.domain.com:8080/buildByToken/buildWithParameters"
fi
```

Screenshot of error through Eclipse:

[image]

**Important notes:**

- Code does get committed properly, repository browser indicates a new version
- The job runs on Jenkins, the history shows that
- Everytime I commit, I get this error message
- I tried adding the flag `--quiet`, but I got the same exit code.

I'm thinking it's due to wget and posting the values?

**Edit #1**

I would like to point out that I'm using the Jenkins [Build Authorization Token Root Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin). I switched to a POST instead of a GET (which works) due to eventually moving onto https and keeping the token out of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret the error message to mean that wget can not write a file with the name *buildWithParameters* in its current directory. Use `wget -O -` to write the output to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

The error is (I think) because it's trying to download the webpage to a local dir. You just need to ping the endpoint to make jenkins build, so I used the --spider (doesn't download), --no-proxy (I was getting cached responses sometimes) and -q (don't output, cuz svn will report it).

`wget --post-data="job=APS-RemoteServerAction&token=SECRET&ACTION=deploy&ASSET_NAME=POST-COMMIT-TEST&DEPLOY_ENV=DEV&REVISION=$REV" "http://my.domain.com:8080/buildByToken/buildWithParameters" --spider --no-proxy -q`